# How to get the shortest time of a sequence of works?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, parallel-processing

I am programming on a process management problem. Say there is a sequence of works which need to be done one by one, you have to finish work1 before work2 for each item. Use the following example:

```
work1   8   6   2   4
work2   3   1   3   12
```

we need to use 8 hours to finish work1 for the first column and another 3 hours, but if we finish column 4 at first, during the next 12 hours, we have some time to do the column 3 and column 2. It is better to put this column at first step.

My intuitive idea, the work2 is the bottleneck, that means, we need to use 3+1+3+12=20 at least to close this deal. That is to say, put work2 process always on working as much as we can. My algorithm: reverse sort the work2 and sort the work1, as we want to keep the work2 process as busy as we can.

This is my algorithms, it looks like to work:

```
class Solution(object):
    def least_time(self, intervals):
        intervals.sort(key = lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
        time1 = time2 = 0 
        print intervals
        for inv in intervals:
            item1, item2 = inv
            if time1 + item1 <= time2 + item2:
                time1 += item1 
                time2 += item2
            else:
                time1 += item1
                time2 = time1 + item2

        return time2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    s = Solution()
    invs = [(8,3), (6,1), (2,3), (4,12)]
    print(s.least_time(invs))




>>>[(4, 12), (2, 3), (8, 3), (6, 1)]
>>>21
```

It is able to finish the thing in above order within 21 hours.

My question is:
1. Are my algorithms correct?
2. How to expand this problem to n works? (work1 -> work2 -> work3 ->...->workn)

Comment: Do you only have 2 processors? And can processor 1 only work on `work1` jobs and processor 2 on `work2` jobs?

Comment: @slider yes, let's assume so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put an example below, but I think a web search finds the answers you actually want.

For the case of two machines, the problem can be solved (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_shop_scheduling#Jobs_consisting_of_multiple_operations) with Johnson's rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_rule).

Since the first reference talks about bodging Johnson's rule to handle the case of more than two machines, I presume that there is no other more satisfactory solution for this case.

Suppose that you have a mix of two sorts of jobs. One takes A two steps and then B three steps. The other takes A three steps and then B two steps. One pattern that seems to work is to alternate the two jobs. A is busy for two steps with B idle. Then B works on that job for three steps while A takes the other sort of job. At the end of that time A hands B a job that took three steps for B to complete in two while A takes on the first sort of job.

So both are continually busy alternating between two and three steps per job.

I don't think this would come out of your pre-sorting algorithm.

One general (but computationally very expensive) algorithm would be to use A* search with a heuristic which said that the time to complete from a particular state was max(time taken by A if kept continuously busy, time taken by B if kept continuously busy). There is a large literature on scheduling problems which unfortunately I don't have in my head - I just know it exists, and that most non-trivial problems turn out to be NP-complete.